# document.getElementById not finding?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

Ok, here is the resulting body from the php.

```
<body>
<div id="outerBox" name="outerBox">

<div id='topNav' name='topNav'>

</div>

Content

<div id='footer' name='footer'>
Footer
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">centerbody();</script>
</body>
```

then here is the `centerbody` function

```
function centerbody(){
    var container = document.getElementById('outerBox');
    var pageWidth = window.innerWidth;
    container.style.marginLeft = '50px';
    container.style.marginRight = '50px';
}
```

Why is the `getElementById` not getting the `outerBox`? I've been using this for a long long time, and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Is `centerbody` actually called? Where is it defined? How do you know `getElementById` does not find the element? Do you get an error? I cannot see anything wrong in the code you posted, you have to provide more information.

Comment: seems to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/zAGQ7/

Comment: centerbody is called right before /body, and it is defined in an external js file, and I tried defining right in the head. Neither one works. I know because Chrome gave an error, and it crashes in FF as well. I put an alert in the beginning for testing, and one in the end. First alert pops up, but not the second.

Comment: Could you let us know what the error is?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null / 
centerbody / 
(anonymous function)

Comment: Ok... as the others showed, the code you posted is correct. So the problem is somewhere in the code you didn't post or it is something you did not tell us about. We cannot help you if we cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: This will take you to it. I hate starting out a project with something so simple that shouldn't be throwing me as much of an issue as it is.  http://djtechy.ipage.com/development/AGC/index.php

Comment: A simple *right click -> view page source* or *right click -> inspect element* would have shown you what the problem is.

Comment: I did, like I said below. Coffee, and sometimes I overlook the simplest of things when I'm looking for something much more complex, expecting it to be something like an ; or something wrong with my JS, not the tags which are something like second nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple typos.  Your title isn't closed nor is your meta tag value.  This is breaking the DOM which is breaking the getElementById.

```
<meta name='keywords' content='Gatlinburg Cabins, Gatlinburg Chalets, Budget Gatlinburg Cabins, Discoung Gatlinburg Cabins, Discount Gatlinburg Chalets, Budget Gatlinburg Chalets, Pet Friendly Cabins, Pet Friendly Chalets, Smoky Mountain Cabins, Smoky Mountain Chalets' />
<title>Awesome Gatlinburg CabinsHome Page</title>
```

Comment: The title does not have to be closed afaik, but the missing quotation mark is the culprit.

Comment: So, that means the answer is not enough coffee... I'm seeing it now. Thanks

Comment: @FelixKling it almost certainly wouldn't have to be particularly so long as the head ends or body starts, but it's also a slippery slope unless you know where you're going.

Comment: Which is true, which is also all the color-coding messing with me as I php this with <<<'s and etc. It's all the variability I'm coding in which is putting the ice on the slope I'm making myself.